# Numerical integration vs symbolic integration in python

Tags: python, sympy, symbolic-math

I want to look at a plot of a function `intensity(r)` versus space, so `r` (radially symmetric).

However, I derive my intensity from `intensity(r) = integrate(integrand(r), (x,0,5))`, where `integrand = exp(-x**2) * exp(np.pi*1j*(-x)) * besselj(0, r*x) * x`.

All the syntax above is using the `sympy` package, so I first define  `x,y = symbols('x r')` .

---

I was using symbolic variables because it seemed to be making visually easier, leaving `r` as a variable until the end, when I plot it and I assign it a numerical value.

However doing that horrible integral with a symbolic variable seems to be taking ages.

- Is there any way of performing numerical integration with symbolic variables?
- Is the only other alternative defining the values of `r` a priori and finding the integral for each one of them?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Aside: when you create a symbolic expression, keep it symbolic. Don't mix in a real float `np.pi` and a complex float `1j`, use SymPy's `pi` and `I` instead.

```
from sympy import exp, pi, I, besselj, symbols
x, r = symbols('x r')
integrand = exp(-x**2) * exp(pi*I*(-x)) * besselj(0, r*x) * x
```

But yes, it doesn't look like SymPy can integrate the product of a Bessel function with `exp(-x**2) * exp(pi*I*(-x))`. This happens already with r replaced by 1, so the symbolic nature of r is beside the point.

To directly answer your question:

> Is there any way of performing numerical integration with symbolic variables?

There is not, like there is no dry water. It's a contradiction in terms.

> Is the only other alternative defining the values of r a priori and finding the integral for each one of them?

Yes. It can be done through SymPy (which will call mpmath):

```
>>> intensity = lambda r_: Integral(integrand.subs(r, r_), (x, 0, 5)).evalf()
>>> intensity(3)
0.0783849036516177 - 0.125648626220306*I
```

It's not quite clear how you plan to plot this function, given that it's complex-valued. Perhaps you meant to plot the absolute value of intensity?

Anyway, integration with SymPy/mpmath (pure Python) is too slow for plotting. You'd be better off with SciPy's `quad` for integration. It does not handle complex integrands, so I integrate the real and complex parts separately.

```
from scipy.integrate import quad
from scipy.special import jn
integrand = lambda x, r: np.exp(-x**2) * np.exp(np.pi*1j*(-x)) * jn(0, r*x) * x
intensity = lambda r: np.sqrt(quad(lambda x: np.real(integrand(x, r)), 0, 5)[0]**2 + quad(lambda x: np.imag(integrand(x, r)), 0, 5)[0]**2)
```

Now `intensity(3)` is evaluated a lot faster than in the previous version. And we can plot it:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
t = np.linspace(0, 3)
plt.plot(t, np.vectorize(intensity)(t))
```

[image: plot]

Comment: Thank you. I forgot to say that the intensity is actually the magnitude of the integrand, which I am assuming I can <code>Abs()</code>?

Comment: Regardless, symblolic takes 4 years to run. Thanks so much, I had not relaised I can still leave my r undefined via a lambda function!

Comment: Actually sorry, if I were to plot this in 3D using a meshgrid, I need to evalute the lambda function for an array of values and it complains. Is it because the lambda funcion cannot handle this?

Comment: Unclear what you mean by 3d plot with meshgrid, given that intensity depends only on r, which is a scalar parameter. In any case, one can't simply stick an array into `intensity(array)`, this is why there is `np.vectorize` in the code.